# What happens when adding constness to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Static assertions all fail. What type is `Constifier` creating for a function pointer?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Constifier;

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T *>
{
    typedef const T *Type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Constifier<int (*)()>::Type, const int (*)()>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Constifier<int (*)()>::Type, int (*const)()>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Constifier<int (*)()>::Type, void>::value, "");
}
```

Comment: in your trait, you are not adding constness to a *function pointer* but to a *pointed* function, but top level cv qualifiers on a function type are ignored (though you can have a const pointer to a function, then you'd use `typedef T * const Type`). btw. you don't need a `typename` keyword here.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I see, it's not dependent type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function pointer is unchanged:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Constifier<int (*)()>::Type, int (*)()>::value, "");
```

You cannot alter a function because it lives in the code section of the memory, so you can think of a function pointer implicity pointing to const already.